# javascript innerHTML adding instead of replacing

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, innerhtml

quick question, i know we can **change** the content of a

`<div id="whatEverId">hello one<div>` by using:

```
document.getElementById("whatEverId").innerHTML="hello two";
```

now, is there a way I can **ADD** stuff to the div instead of replacing it???
so i can get

`<div id="whatEverId">hello one hello two<div>`

*(using something similar of course)*

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
<div id="whatever">hello one</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("whatever").innerHTML += " hello two";
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

Notice that using `element.innerHTML += 'content'` would empty `input`s and `textarea`s to their default, blank state, unclick checkboxes, as well as removing any events attached to those elements (such as `onclick`, `on hover` etc.) because the whole `innerHTML` would be reinterpreted by the browser, which means `.innerHTML` is emptied and filled again from scratch with the combined content.

If you need to keep the state, you'd need to create a new element (a `<span>` for instance) and append it to the current element, as in:

```js
let newElement = 'span'
newElement.innerHTML = 'new text'
document.getElementById('oldElement').appendChild(newElement)
```

Comment: let newElement = document.createElement('span'); I think?

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById("whatEverId").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("whatEverId").innerHTML +  "hello two" + document.getElementById("whatEverId").innerHTM ;
```

Answer (score 2):

What jcomeau_ictx suggested is an inefficient way of editing the innerHTML. 
Check Ben cherry's PPT http://www.bcherry.net/talks/js-better-faster

The correct way will be detaching the element and making changes to it and then appending it back to the parent node.
Use https://gist.github.com/cowboy/938767 Native javascript from this gist to 
detach element.

Comment: Please explain. First link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you are appending, you can just change your = to a +=

document.getElementById("whatEverId").innerHTML += 'hello two';

If prefixing

document.getElementById("whatEverId").innerHTML = 'hello two' + document.getElementById("whatEverId").innerHTML;

Although I would highly recommend using jQuery or MooTools javascript libraries/frameworks to do this sort of thing. If you're adding tags not just text nodes, then you should use the DOM createElement or one of the aforementioned libraries/frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by appending div string like this..

document.getElementById('div_id').innerHTML += 'Hello Two';