# How do I section out an Index and have it print on a new line in JavaScript and HTML with an onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

I have an index that looks like this

```
var quotes = ["string 1",
  "string 2",
  "string 3",
  "string 4",
  "string 5",
  "string 6",
  "string 7",
  "string 8",
  "string 9",
  "string 10", //this pattern continues for a while
];
```

I am trying to section out my array into smaller blocks, but I don't want to create a new array each time. I am doing that by using this code:

```
function openingText() {
  var opening = quotes.slice(0, 7);
  for (var x in opening) {
    opening[x] = '>' + opening[x];
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = opening[x];
  }
}
```

I have assigned this function to an `onclick` event in my HTML file.
When I run the code `string 7` prints, but nothing else.

How can I make it print from 0 and iterate through each string to 7 with an `onclick`?

Comment: 1. I don't recomend you to use for-in for arrays; 2. Your code has no closing brackets (probably it's just a part of the code). So, if printing part of the code is out of the `for` body, it'll execute with last value of `x`. Also, by `document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = opening[x];` you are not adding, but rewriting content of the element.

Comment: `document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = opening[x];` You are not adding but overwriting the current value `=` !==  `+=`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript innerHTML adding instead of replacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594014/javascript-innerhtml-adding-instead-of-replacing)

Comment: That makes sense, I get what you're saying. I will change somethings around and see if it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for`-loop you are overriding the `innerHTML` seven times. You have:

`document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = opening[x];`

you want:
`document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += opening[x];`

This way, you will append to the previous value instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Thank you! I at least understand what I was doing wrong and why, which is really helpful.